# Wordpress: admin_footer_text text not appended

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to use `admin_footer_text` in my plugin to add `html` into admin page. it works. but I've another plugin install that's using the same hook `admin_footer_text`. my plugin is overwriting the html code of previous one. I want it to append not to overwrite.

here is how I'm using the code

```
add_filter('admin_footer_text', 'my_footer_admin', 1);
function my_footer_admin($default){
    ob_start();
    echo 'some text';
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it like the following example

```
add_filter('admin_footer_text', 'my_footer_admin', 1);

function my_footer_admin( $default ) {
    ob_start();
    echo 'some text';
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    return $default $content;
}
```

Comment: thank you Jason! your solution is the best one. btw, I resolved it just by the following code.
`add_filter('admin_footer_text', 'my_footer_admin', 1);
function my_footer_admin( $default ) {
    echo 'some text';
}`